# Align text in jquery mobile checkbox with added image

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've used the solution here  http://jsfiddle.net/KADqA/23/ to add an image to a jquery mobile checkbox, and it works fine, but now the label text is out of alignment with the checkbox images (too high) and I can't figure out how to center it with css.

Here's a portion of the code to generate the html

```
<input type=checkbox id=chk" + ingindex + " class='chk chk" + ingindex + "' name=chk" + ingindex + "><label for=chk" + ingindex + ">" + item + "<a href='#' data-rel='dialog' ><img class=recimg src='http://webrecipemanager.com/images/recipe/" + image + "' alt='" + name + "'></a></label>
```

This is the generated html from firebug

```
<div id="div0" class="drag inaisle ui-draggable" name="div0">draggable=Object { 

element={...}, options={...}, started=

false

, more...}jQuery16405345229560181788=Object { events={...}, handle=function()}
<div class="ui-checkbox">
<input id="chk0" class="chk chk0" type="checkbox" name="chk0">checkboxradio=Object { element={...}, options={...}, label={...}, more...}jQuery16405345229560181788=Object { events={...}, handle=function()}virtualMouseBindings=Object { vmousedown=

true

, vclick=

true

}
<label class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off ui-btn-up-i" for="chk0" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="i">corners=

true

shadow=

false

iconshadow=

true

wrapperEls=

"span"

icon=

"checkbox-off"

theme=

"i"

buttonElements=Object { bcls=

"ui-btn ui-btn-up-i ui-b...er-all ui-btn-icon-left"

, outer=label.ui-btn, inner=span.ui-btn-inner, more...}jQuery16405345229560181788=Object { events={...}, handle=function()}virtualMouseBindings=Object { vmouseover=

true

, vclick=

true

}
</div>
<input id="item0" type="hidden" value="1/2 c Baking Cocoa" name="item0">
<input id="ing0" type="hidden" value="Baking Cocoa" name="ing0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Firebug or another developer tool to examine the CSS to manipulate...
[see the docu](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify. The set of of theme classes (global) and semantic structural
>   classes (widget-specific) added to elements provide a rich set of
>   possible selectors against which to target style overrides. We
>   recommend adding an external stylesheet to the head, placed after the
>   structure and theme stylesheet references, that contain all your style
>   overrides. This allows you to easily update to newer versions of the
>   library because overrides are kept separate from the library code.

In your case add the following

```
  <style>
  .ui-mobile a img, .ui-mobile fieldset {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  </style>
```

see modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX3Ar/) and the complete code of the working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  .ui-mobile a img, .ui-mobile fieldset {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="OptIn" id="OptIn"/>
            <label for="OptIn">Receive E-mails From Us</label>

           <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="cbox" name="tandc" id="tandc"/>
            <label for="tandc">I agree to the <a href="#tc" data-rel="dialog" ><img src="http://dummyimages.com/25x25" /></a></label>
       </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="tc">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>T and C</h1>
    </div>
    Read me
  </div>

  <script>
  $('.ui-btn-text').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $("#tandc[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.children('a').length) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#tc', {
            transition : 'pop',
            role       : 'dialog'
        });
    }
    stateOfCheckbox(checked);
  });

  function stateOfCheckbox(checked) {
    $('#home').live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
        $("#tandc[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",checked).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me as my generated html doesn't contain the same elements. I have tried to add the generated html from firebug, sorry it's a bit of a mess

Comment: see the updated answer, probably that helps... What do you mean by `generated html from firebug`? Firebug doesn't generate html but you can examine the html and css to override it...

Comment: I just meant I copied the html from the inspector in firebug. I don't see any fieldset element, don't know if this is due to the platform I'm developing on, or because I am adding the content dynamically. But I'm still trying to figure out which element/s to apply the vertical-align to